# Unable to connect to database using WAMP

Tags: control-panel, database

I turned debugging on with my local installation, and find out that i cant get into database.

A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\wamp\www\siteA\system\codeigniter\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124

I have checked the config and database.php files and all should be good to go.
Any idea what i could do, to get into CP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it could be a parameter problem, or a problem with the wamp server that cause this error. Debugging not affect the database parameters.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you'll need to setup a multi-environment `/system/expressionengine/config/database.php` file. Here's a glimpse of how I typically set mine up:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  == 'PRODUCTIONSERVER.com') {

    $active_group = 'production';

} elseif ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  == 'DEVELOPMENTSERVER.com') {

    $active_group = 'development';

} elseif ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  == 'YOURLOCALDOMAIN.dev') {

    $active_group = 'local';

} else {

    $active_group = 'production';
}

$db['local']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['local']['username'] = 'root';
$db['local']['password'] = 'YOUR PASSWORD';
$db['local']['database'] = 'DATABASENAME';
$db['local']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['local']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['local']['dbprefix'] = 'exp_';
$db['local']['swap_pre'] = 'exp_';
$db['local']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['local']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['local']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
$db['local']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['local']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['local']['cachedir'] = '{$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]}SYSTEMFOLDER/expressionengine/cache/db_cache/';

$db['development']['hostname'] = 'DEV HOST NAME';
$db['development']['username'] = 'DEV USER NAME';
$db['development']['password'] = 'DEV PASSWORD';
$db['development']['database'] = 'DEV DATABASE';
$db['development']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['development']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['development']['dbprefix'] = 'exp_';
$db['development']['swap_pre'] = 'exp_';
$db['development']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['development']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['development']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
$db['development']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['development']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['development']['cachedir'] = '{$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]}SYSTEMFOLDER/expressionengine/cache/db_cache/';

$db['production']['hostname'] = 'PRODUCTION HOST NAME';
$db['production']['username'] = 'PRODUCTION USER NAME';
$db['production']['password'] = 'PRODUCTION PASSWORD';
$db['production']['database'] = 'PRODUCTION DATABASE';
$db['production']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['production']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['production']['dbprefix'] = 'exp_';
$db['production']['swap_pre'] = 'exp_';
$db['production']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['production']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['production']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
$db['production']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['production']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['production']['cachedir'] = '{$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]}SYSTEMFOLDER/expressionengine/cache/db_cache/';


?>
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

hummm try to have a look on your .htaccess file.
 And have a look to in the index.php in the site root to verify the system path:

```
 $system_path = './system';
```

The path on your local/wamp server could be different from the production site

Answer (score 0):

The basing settings inside (database.php in the config folder) when using Wamp for EE are:

```
    $db['expressionengine']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $db['expressionengine']['username'] = 'root';
    $db['expressionengine']['password'] = '';
    $db['expressionengine']['database'] = 'name_of_your_database';
    $db['expressionengine']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';$db['expressionengine']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
    $db['expressionengine']['dbprefix'] = 'exp_';
    $db['expressionengine']['swap_pre'] = 'exp_';
    $db['expressionengine']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['expressionengine']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['expressionengine']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
    $db['expressionengine']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['expressionengine']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['expressionengine']['cachedir'] = '/localhost/system/expressionengine/cache/db_cache/';
```

Comment: Thanks but I've changed the root-user to have password in wamp, and im trying to use the database imported to wamp, from my live site. Basic installation of EE went just fine and all works with it. But when i change the database to be using the other, site is closed and cant access to CP.

Comment: Forgot to say, that database connection do then work but EE itself gives this error when I try to access CP: 
You are not authorized to perform this action. And http://localhost/siteA is redirecting me to example.com. So I must be missing something?